# Perforce command to find newly added file in particular depot path

Tags: perforce, p4v

I we have one perforce depot path where all projects are located. Actually i would like to know which project got added in last 24hrs. For that we have one file Say 'project.xml' which is common for all projects.

Is there any command to find newly added project.xml file in last 24hrs ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular `p4 files` command with a filespec that matches your filename and a date range to specify the window you're interested in:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 files ...project.xml@2020/04/06,@now
//stream/main/dir/project.xml#1 - add change 151 (text)
```

Comment: In this case we need to give complete path of project.xml file ? Could you share the example? In my case i want to know the newly added project.xml file by just giving the root of all project. Is that work for me?

Comment: `...` refers to everything under the current client directory.  Use `//...project.xml` if you want to go from the depot root.

Comment: to be clear: the `...` in my answer doesn't mean "fill in the path here," it means literally three dots.  :)  That's the Perforce wildcard for "match any string", which in the context of a file path is effectively a recursive search.

Comment: Thanks Sam. It works file. But is there a way to do this for last 24 hours without having to constantly change the command with date ?

Comment: Nope, "relative" specifiers with dates aren't a thing.  You'd need to do a little bit of scripting to get the current date/time and then subtract 1 from the date.